# Relation between central and mean density in a White Dwarf (polytropic model)

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, astrophysics, white-dwarfs

I'm currently studying the radius of a white dwarf and, in deriving some useful equations, I've seen my professor use the following relation: $\bar\rho=\frac{\rho_c}{6}$ when using a polytropic model $P(r)=\rho(r)^\gamma$ with $\gamma=\frac{5}{3}$, but I can't figure out why that holds...

I'm thinking maybe one can integrate $\frac{1}{V}\int_0^R \rho 4\pi r^2 dr = \bar\rho$ substituting the pressure where the density stands and using the initial conditions $P(0)=P_c=\rho_c^{\frac{5}{3}}$ and $P(R)=\rho(R)=0$, but I don't know what expression for $P$ I should be substituting there. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: It has nothing to do with the poly tropic model.  It has to do with how p varies radially.

Comment: And how could I get that result?

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea.

Comment: Fair enough I guess

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-pressure-distribution-a-and-mass-distribution-b-for-the-charged-solid-lines-and_fig1_262416637

Comment: @ChetMiller it has everything to do with the adoption of a particular polytropic model. Given that you don't know where the result comes from, your initial comment is a bit puzzling.

Comment: @ProfRob2 Very interesting.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard result obtained by numerically solving the Lane-Emden equation for a polytrope with $n=3/2$ (equivalent to an adiabatic index of $\gamma = 5/3$).

It can be found in any textbook or set of lecture notes that treat polytopes as a means of solving the stellar structure equations (e.g. [these lecture notes](https://www.astro.princeton.edu/%7Egk/A403/polytrop.pdf)).

Comment: Clarifying, thanks!!!